# Problems with resizing when wireframing in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm quite the novice when it comes to Visio, and I can't say that it has been a very pleasant experience so far..

I have a set of shapes that are copies of one another. They are to be placed into a panel to illustrate a segment control. Now I want to have all the shapes selected and resize their width together to find the right width for them inside the panel. The problem I'm experiencing is that once I start resizing their width they "pop" in height making them about 50% higher than before I started resizing.

**This is how it behaves:**

*Before resizing*
[image]

*Started resizing*
[image]

There is probably some relation between the height/width of shapes in Visio that I'm unaware of that is the cause of what's happening, but I can't seem to figure out how to get around it.

Btw, it's not as easy as setting back the height once I've adjusted the width. Once the shapes have popped to a new height I can't lower the height any more.

Comment: Can you share at least part of the original Visio diagram? It might help someone reproduce and investigate the problem.

Comment: @saveenr hi saveenr. Thanks, I actually found what the problem was. Unfortunately I forgot to post it here, I'll do that now. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was with the text elements and their heigh, which were placed inside each button element. As I started resizing the button elements their height was automatically adjusted to the height of the text element container, which were higher than the text itself and also varied in height, as seen in the second image.

I simply worked around it by temporarily moving the text elements outside the buttons when I made the resize, and then moved them back in when the resizing was done.